# How to set multiple request flags under OnBeforeResourceLoad event

Tags: cefsharp

I am intending to set multiple request related flags available under CefSharp OnBeforeResourceLoad event but I could not find a syntax to do that. Please help.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code and the flag you are attempting to set.

Comment: I want to set both "request.Flags = UrlRequestFlags.AllowStoredCredentials;" and "request.Flags = UrlRequestFlags.StopOnRedirect;" under OnBeforeResourceLoad event

Answer (score 0):

They're [Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-7.0) so you just combine them together using a bitwise `OR`.

```cs
request.Flags = UrlRequestFlags.AllowStoredCredentials | UrlRequestFlags.StopOnRedirect;
```